# Eclipse auto completion with method parameter type name

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Currently I get this result with Eclipse auto completion.

```
System.console().printf(format, args)
```

Of course, Eclipse shows the parameter types as popup, but I want the types to be displayed in front of parameter names too. Like this.

```
System.console().printf(String format, Object ... args)    // `String`, `Object` inserted automatically.
```

Can I configure Eclipse to show the parameter types too?

Comment: *Eclipse shows the parameter types as popup, but it would be better if it shows types too* What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. Eclipse auto completion only suggests valid syntax, while your demand is not valid java code.

An alternative for you might be to open the "Declaration" view or the "JavaDoc" view. Both will always show the declaration/JavaDoc of the currently selected element while you are typing. Therefore you could see the method declaration/javadoc when writing that method call.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*
Whoever came across this old question. You can use eclipse code mining now:

[parameter name hint for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926238/parameter-name-hint-for-eclipse/58198356#58198356)