# parameter name hint for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Intellij includes a nice parameter name hint feature ([Intellij idea - how to always show method parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627924/intellij-idea-how-to-always-show-method-parameter-names))

Is it planned for Eclipse incorporate it too?

Comment: Not sure. There might be plugins.but why not use idea.its best

Comment: @minigeek It's paid.

Comment: @lyuboslavkanev there is community edition which is free(ultimate is paid)

Comment: @minigeek True, but the community edition lacks support for essential features like JavaEE, Spring, Tomcat, Perforce and more.

Comment: really looking for this feature in eclipse

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Angelo Zerr is working on this in his "JDT Codemining" project at https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining.

It won't be part of the upcoming Eclipse Photon release in June, but may be part of one of the next releases (Eclipse is switching from the yearly release cycle to to having a release every 3 month, so the next release will be in September).

He writes that by starring his project on github you can increase likeliness of this being included soon and you can help by testing and reporting issues.

Answer (score 49):

**Update 2019:** *Code Mining* is part of Eclipse now (Version: 2019-09 - but also some versions earlier).

`Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Code Minings -> [x] Show method parameter names`

[image: screenshot of code mining and the setting]
(screenshot is spring tool suite STS which is based on eclipse)

Comment: A pitty eclipse has such mediocre default settings for it's features.